Rxjs - retry() operator with timer() in delay - chained observable does not work
I´m trying to do a retry interceptor for angular application, but doing some process before return the timer() in delay field fo retry operator.
How could i do this work?
I did:
@Injectable()
export class RetryInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
 public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      retry({
        count: 1,
        delay: (error: HttpErrorResponse, retryAttempt: number): Observable<number> => {
          if (error.status !== 400) 
            return throwError(() => error);
          
          return this.httpClient.get(...url).pipe(
            tap((data) => doSomething(data))
          ).pipe(
            switchMap(() => timer(retryAttempt))
          );
        },
      }),
      catchError((error) => this.errorHandler(request, error))
    );
  }
}

But only works if i return the timer() directly. So:
@Injectable()
export class RetryInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
 public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      retry({
        count: 1,
        delay: (error: HttpErrorResponse, retryAttempt: number): Observable<number> => {
          if (error.status !== 400) 
            return throwError(() => error);
          
          return timer(retryAttempt);
        },
      }),
      catchError((error) => this.errorHandler(request, error))
    );
  }
}

works.

Are you sure that the code right before the timer returns something? this.httpClient.get(...url)? Try adding a tap with a console.log, I'm guessing nothing happens and therefore the timer is just never even reached.

I never tried it, so maybe I'm wrong about it, but I think that when you call "this.httpClient.get(...URL)" inside an interceptor, this request should be also intercepted by Angular, and it could cause an endless recursion. Maybe StackBlitz example could help.
